# How do I check running time?

Tags: python, performance, runtime, complexity-theory

What are the ways to time my Python code precisely, preferably using the built-in modules? Though algorithms are synonymous with efficient sorting, sometimes, adding a *single* digit to the input makes the code for one run incomprehensibly slower. One could not sit and wait for all that time.

Comment: [timeit](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can encapsulate pieces of code in 'timed' box:

```
t0 = time.time()
<your code here>
elapsed = time.time() - t0
```

or use a profiler.

The time solution is a little bit inefficient and profiler can be very dispersive in complex cases.

Anyway if you can add a library, i'm the main developer of [perf_tool](https://github.com/glaucouri/perf_tool) very useful for these use cases.